# How do I animate a right-angle triangle inside a circle (hypotenuse of the triangle is the radius of the circle)

Tags: animation, objects, geometry

As I move the radius of the circle I need to show the triangle moving showing the right angle moving (on the x-axis).

Basically the three points of the triangle are: the centre of the circle (A), a point in the circumference (B) and one on the x-axis (C) - so that line drawn from B to the x-axis is always perpendicular to the x-axis and remains perpendicular as you move point (B) (or angle CAB from 0 - 180 degrees).

**Here a drawing of what I have in mind.**

[image]

Comment: Hello, I guess you mean "hypotenuse of the triangle is the **diameter** of the circle" right?

Comment: Sorry no. The hypotenuse is the radius. So basically the 3 points of the triangle are: the centre of the circle (A), a point in the circumference (B) and one on the x-axis (C) - so that line drawn from B to the x-axis is always perpendicular to the x-axis and remains perpendicular as you move point (B) from 0 - 90 degrees. Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, then my answer is wrong or not applicable to your case. However, I find rather difficult to figure what you have in mind. Would you please add a sketch to your question? In fact, if you assign the hypotenuse of a right-angle triangle (*i.e.* both its length and position) then you can form a right-angle triangle only if the other vertex lies on the circumference that your hypotenuse is the diameter of.

Comment: @NicolaSap I think (and I could be wrong) that (s)he's saying that the C point isn't on the edge of the circle.  So A is in the middle, B is an arbitrary point on the circle, and C is the point on the X axis that has the same X coordinate as B.  N Dib, can you verify this?

Comment: Thanks both of you. The diagram that has been added makes it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duane Dibbey's answer is good and solves your problem, however - for completeness - I'm posting another one that will leave you more freedom to move the hypotenuse around instead of having it span linearly from 0 to 360.

1. **Create a triangle starting from a plane.**

   [image]

   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>>`Mesh`>`Plane`. Enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Remove one of the 4 vertices (<kbd>RMB</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd>>`Vertices`), move the others into positions `0,0`, `1,0`, `1,1` (<kbd>RMB</kbd> then <kbd>G</kbd>, holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for fixed increments), select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and make a face (<kbd>F</kbd>).

   Then you can exit edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and scale it down by 1/sqrt(2) (<kbd>S</kbd> `0.7071`) to make the hypotenuse 1 unit long.
2. **Hook the two moving vertices to two new empties.**

   [image]

   Enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select one vertex (<kbd>RMB</kbd>) then hook it: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>>`Hook to new object`. Repeat for the other vertex. This will create two new empties in the scene.
3. **Create a central empty and parent the top-right empty to it.**

   [image]

   Exit edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>). Make sure that your 3d cursor is still in the center (otherwise do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>>`Cursor to center`), and add a new empty (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>>`Empty`>`Plain Axes`).

   Select the top-right empty (<kbd>RMB</kbd>) ant then the center empty (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>). Set parent with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.
4. **Constrain the X-location of the bottom-right empty to the top-right empty.**

   [image]

   Select the bottom-right empty (<kbd>RMB</kbd>), go to the `Constraints` panel and add a new Object Constraint of type `Copy Location`. Link it to the top-right empty with the eye-dropper tool, and deselect `Y` and `Z`.
5. **Done!** You can now rotate the center empty and the triangle will change accordingly.

   [image]

   In the object properties of the empties you can change their display type and size, if you think they are too big and cluttering.

Comment: I've been playing with something very similar to this. However, I've also tried to remedy the distortion of the outlines that happens with my answer, and this solution falls just as short as mine, and this also has the drawback of the normals pointing the wrong way in the second and fourth quadrant. This is definitely good, and I've upvoted, but it's not ideal. But then again, nor is mine.

Comment: The problem with normals can be solved by ticking "Double sided" in the Object Data panel. The outlines are rather difficult to make well: the wireframe modifier is not great for 2D shapes and behaves oddly for small angles. One can create a complex mesh made of three non linked rectangles (one per edge) and then hooking the short edge of each to the three empties, but this would be a rather complicate answer to the original question.

Comment: Super - you are a genious...

Answer (score 3):

Start by adding a single vertex (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd> or *Add* -> *Single Vert* -> *Add Single Vert*). You should be in edit mode by default after doing this, but if not <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode.

Extrude by 1 along the X axis (<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>), then extrude by 1 along the Y axis (<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>). Select everything, by hitting <kbd>A</kbd> twice. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to make a face.

[image]

If you want only the outline of the triangle, press <kbd>I</kbd> followed by some sufficiently small number then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>F</kbd>. <kbd>Tab</kbd> out of edit mode.

[image]

Go to the object properties and add the following into the Scale boxes:

If you prefer degrees:
X: `#cos(radians(360*(frame-1)/100))`
Y: `#sin(radians(360*(frame-1)/100))`

If you prefer radians:
X: `#cos(2*pi360*(frame-1)/100)`
Y: `#sin(2*pi*(frame-1)/100)`

The hash signs are mandatory. They tell Blender that you're entering a driver rather than a static value. If you edit the driver later, the hash signs won't show up, and you shouldn't re-add them. Once the driver is created, Blender knows it's a driver without being told again.

[image]

`frame` is the current frame number, and the reason I subtract 1 is that Blender starts at frame 1, while the parametric equations for a circle start at 0. `360` or `2*pi` is the angle of a full circle, and `100` is the number of frames it will take to complete a full circle.

The result:

[image]

As you can see, the triangle's outline gets scaled as well, and there's certainly room for improvement there, however, here's the .blend.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Duane. I see now that this is quite complex and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @NDib I have an idea that may remedy the disappearing outline. I haven't had time to test it yet, but if I get it to work, I'll update my answer.